# jQuery $(element).click() doesn't work on IPhone

Tags: jquery, mobile

I have this jQuery script that allows someone to land on a web page, and if the url contains the string `playdefault=1` as a parameter at the end of the url, then jQuery initiates the click of a link with the ID `#Nav_Products`.

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
  if(window.location.search.indexOf('playdefault=1') > -1) { 
     jQuery('#Nav_Products').click() 
  }
})
```

My issue is how to make the code above also work on iPhone. How can I edit the code above to not only continue to do what it does for desktop users, but also allow mobile users to perform the same functionality.

Comment: it has noting to do with a touch

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can use `window.location.href = your_url`, that's should a redirect a user to your url :) and it's pure javascript, I don't think you need `$(window).load` ..

```
if(window.location.search.indexOf('playdefault=1') > -1){ 
    window.location.href = your_url;
 }
```

Comment: Looking into this still. Thanks for the help Marko!